# Growth series for the lamplighter group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03569) gives the [growth series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)) of the [lamplighter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group) as

$$ \frac{(1+x)(1-x^2)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1-x^2+x^3)^2(1-x-x^2)} = 1 + 3x + 6x^2 + 8x^3 + 10x^4 + \ldots $$

The first 3 coefficients seem to be correct. However, I get 12 group elements with a word norm of 3. They are the following:

\begin{array}{l l}
  ttt & at^{-1}a \\
  tta & at^{-1}t^{-1} \\
  tat & t^{-1}at \\
  tat^{-1} & t^{-1}at^{-1} \\
  att & t^{-1}t^{-1}a \\
  ata & t^{-1}t^{-1}t^{-1}
\end{array}

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: The beginning of this expansion is correct (checked on Wolfram Alpha): $ 1 + 3x + 6x^2 + 8x^3 + 10x^4 + 12 x^5 +19 x^6+31 x^7 + 56 x^8 + 92 x^9+155x^{10}+243x^{11}+401 x^{12} +\ldots$ with a growth rate of coefficients given by golden ratio; example $401/243 \approx \Phi.$

Comment: @JeanMarie That's what I thought. But why I am getting 12 3-norm elements instead of 8?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not enough acquainted with this theory to give a thorough advice...

Comment: In the paper under question, they use a generating set of two elements {a,t}. Can you tell us what is the correspondence between these and the elements you call T, R and L? I don't understand your notation.

Comment: Indeed, the growth series will depend on the generating set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. On page 6 of that paper, equation $(3.5)$ is given as:
$$f_{G\wr\mathbb{Z}}(x)=\frac{f_G(x)(1-x^2)^2(1+xf_G(x))}{(1-x^2f_G(x))^2(1-xf_G(x))}$$

On substituting $(1+x)$ for $f_G(x)$, I get:

$$f_{{\cal{L}}_2}(x)=\frac{(1+x)(1-x^2)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1-x^2-x^3)^2(1-x-x^2)}$$

And when expanded, the result seems to agree with you:

$$1 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 12 x^3 + 22 x^4 + 40 x^5 + 71 x^6 + 123 x^7 + 212 x^8 + 360 x^9 + 607 x^{10} +...$$

In the working at the bottom of the same page, a $^2$ goes missing, and then $(-x^2)(+x)$ becomes $+x^3$ in the denominator. It's just a mistake.